# How to return multiple values in MASM

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I have tried to pass multiple parameters like this code to calculate (a-b)^3:

```
diffcube:push bp
         mov bp,sp
         mov ax,[bp+4]
         sub ax,[bp+6]
         mov bp,ax
         mul bp
         mul bp
         pop bp
         ret 4
```

It is easy to pass parameters by using stack, but how can I return multiple values in a procedure in MASM?(Obviously, the number of registers is always limited.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard calling convention that supports returning multiple values, since there is no way to do this in C.

In C, you define a struct (or, more generally, a user-defined type), allocate memory for an instance of that type, initialize its fields, and return a pointer to it. (Alternatively, you can have the caller allocate the memory for the struct, and pass in a pointer to it.) You can do the same thing in assembly language.

Or, you can define a custom calling convention and then return the values however you like. For example, you could return them in specific, defined registers of your own choosing. Or, you could have the caller allocate the necessary amount of space on the stack, and then store the values into those slots.

As long as the caller of your function is aware of and adheres to its calling convention, you don't have a problem. When writing entirely in assembly language, you can do this easily, but you will run into problems if you try to interface this code with C or any other language.

Comment: Note that there is no addressing mode of the form `[sp+4]`. You sure you know 8086 assembly?

Comment: @fuz It's a forgivable mistake, x86 is full of historical, non-sense, artefacts. I don't think that's enough to question Cody's knowledge...

Comment: Ugh, not sure at all. I write 32-bit assembly code. Sorry.

Comment: @CodyGray The 8086 only allows memory operands with bx, bp, si, di, bx + si, bx + di, bp + si, bp + di as the base registers and an optional 8 or 16 bit displacement. A 16 bit absolute address is possible, too. You cannot access the stack through sp, which is why setting up a stack frame is more or less required in every function that wants to access stack operands.

Comment: Yes, you are right, of course, @fuz. Thanks for pointing that out. I vaguely remember that from *Zen of Assembly Language*, and your first comment was enough to refresh my memory. The 8086 was long before my time, and I have focused exclusively on the 386 and later for practical reasons.

Comment: @MargaretBloom I think x86 is still full of life XD.

Comment: I have a question about why "you will run into problems if you try to interface this code with C or any other language." @CodyGray

Comment: Of course I believe that x86 is full of life. The issue is whether the 16-bit 8086 is full of life. And while it's true that you can do some *very* impressive things on such a system, I'm not sure it's worth learning (or remembering) today. As for your question, @kon, what I mean is that if you adopt a custom calling convention, you cannot interface the code with any other language because the compiler for that other language will not know about your calling convention. For interop purposes, your asm code needs to use a standard calling convention that a compiler uses, like stdcall or cdecl.

Comment: I am learning assembly by myself for reverse engineering. In our country, the most popular opinion is "8086CPU is easier to learn for the beginner. What's more, 16-bit assembly is a subset of 32-bit assembly". Since I have no relevant knowledge about assembly before so I choose 8086CPU to practice. As for my question, take C and inline assembly for example, you mean if I want to call a function written in C, I need to use cdecl in asm code, right?

Comment: @Kon Reverse engineering is a good reason to learn, but you'll be reverse engineering 32-bit and/or 64-bit code, so it makes more sense to learn that. Yeah, 16-bit assembly is a subset of 32-bit, but there's a *lot* more to it, and you'll learn a lot of outdated practices (that would now be *bad* practices) and clutter your mind with a bunch of irrelevant and misleading factoids. I've seen a lot of programmers afflicted with this disease. :-) You can learn 32-bit programming with a 386 without adding any more complexity. That's what I would recommend.

Comment: Anyway, inline assembly is something completely different. I'm talking about writing code in a separate assembly module, and then trying to call that function from a C program. That won't work if you choose a custom calling convention—the C compiler won't know how to call it, and it will smash the stack when it tries to do so. You can still shoot yourself in the foot with inline assembly, though. Inline assembly should virtually *never* write to the stack. And inline assembly is a *terrible* way to learn assembly language programming.

Comment: @CodyGray **A million thanks.** There is still a long way to go for me.XD

Answer (score 2):

In the classic calling conventions *cdecl* and *stdcall* you can only return one value as far as I am concerned. That value is returned in `al`, `ax`, or `dx:ax` depending on its size.

However, it is easy to make your own calling convention to return more values. For example, the calling convention employed by Go returns additional values on the stack, overwriting (?) the arguments. If more values need to be returned, extra space needs to be allocated by the caller before calling the function.

Comment: Why do classic conventions choose to return only one value? By allocating necessary space in the stack returning multiple values is possible and convenient.

Comment: @Kon Not sure. Few programming languages allow the return of more than one value. In mathematics, that's uncommon, too.

Comment: That's what makes me confused. I am wondering why the programming language just returns one value from all the beginning, like C.

Comment: @Kon Many programming languages, especially early ones, are *expression oriented.* Functions with more than one return value don't make a lot of sense in such a language and are clumsy to use. It's much easier to just pass a pointer and return the extra data through that pointer.